# TypeError: string indices must be integers - Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've found an "TypError" and I don't know how to solve it anymore. Please, some help. I'll really appreciate an explanation if is possible.

My code:

```
import json

input = '''{
  "text":"Sample data",
  "subjects":[
    {
      "id":"A",
      "quant":10
    },
    {
      "id":"B",
      "quant":9
    },
    {
      "id":"C",
      "quant":8
    },
    {
      "id":"D",
      "quant":7
    },
    {
      "id":"E",
      "quant":6
    }]}
'''

info = json.loads(input)

count = 0
total = 0
for item in info:
    value = item["subjects"][0]["quant"]
    value = int(value)
    total += value
    count += count

print 'Count: ', count    
print 'Sum: ', total
```

Error:

> ; exit; {u'text': u'Sample data', u'subjects': [{u'quant': 10, u'id':
>   u'A'}, {u'quant': 9, u'id': u'B'}, {u'quant': 8, u'id': u'C'},
>   {u'quant': 7, u'id': u'D'}, {u'quant': 6, u'id': u'E'}]} Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/macme/Documents/Python/test_Json.py",
>   line 61, in 
>       value = item["subjects"][0]["quant"] TypeError: string indices must be integers logout Saving session... ...copying shared history...
>   ...saving history...truncating history files... ...completed.
>
> [Process completed]

Comment: Sorry about the error box formatting.

Answer (score 5):

`info` is a dict but you're iterating it like a list. I think you want to iterate on `info['subjects']`.

```
for item in info['subjects']:
  value = int(item['quant'])
```

Comment: Thank you, Dan. You really help me because now I understood why I got this error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is not working how you think it does.

`for item in info` loops over the keys of your dictionary, i.e. over 'text' and 'subjects'. Then you try do index into these strings with another string, which is bound to fail.